# Actionbar centered title with buttons

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I would like to center the title in the action bar, while having action icons next to it(and ignoring them for the gravity setting).

I would like to have this:
[image]

Instead I have this:
[image]

Here is my code:

```
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

    ActionBar.LayoutParams params = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.top_bar));
    actionBar.setCustomView(LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.actionbar_layout, null), params); 
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

My layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/launcher_icon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/actionbar_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxHeight="1dp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:paddingLeft="48dp"
        android:paddingRight="48dp"
        android:text="Bacon ipsum"
        android:textColor="#777777"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

So my problem is, centering the title only works, if I have 0 actionbar items next to it, as soon as I add an item, the centering gets screwed up.
It would also be great, if I could use the up affordance button with it(which also screws up the centering now).

Any help would be appreciated.

I don't wan to implement my own actionbar item/button logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this in the TextView:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/actionbar_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:maxHeight="1dp"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:paddingLeft="48dp"
    android:paddingRight="48dp"
    android:text="Bacon ipsum"
    android:textColor="#777777"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
```

Comment: Sadly, I can't just set the padding and leave it there, I have to keep turning it on and off, depending, if there is an action item to the right of it. Oh well, this sucks less than implementing the buttons myself, so I think this would be the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

1. Remove the launcher icon from your RelativeLayout.
2. Change the width of the RelativeLayout to `wrap_content`
3. Remove:

   actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
   actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
   actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
4. Add:

   ```
   ActionBar.LayoutParams lp = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(

   ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, Gravity.CENTER);

   actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM)
   actionBar.setCustomView(yourInflatedCustomView, lp);
   ```

Comment: This should have been the accepted answer. Tamas, you should have given it a chance :) There is just a missing line: ActionBar#setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM).

Comment: It works for me too. Unbelieve... i'm spend our for this. cheers

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to implement to the text this code?

```
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```

Comment: the problem is, that the action items take up space next to the custom view, so even if I center it in the layout, I still have to play with the padding, just like user2203377 suggested.